# React frontend POST / PUTS to Rails 5 API backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, rails-api, fetch-api

I've got a Rails  5 API with a React frontend running in a /client directory. I'm trying to implement all of the CRUD actions for a resource via the React frontend. 
The React frontend is running on port 3000, and the Rails API backend is running on port 3001. I have CORS installed / enabled on Rails:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'localhost:3001'

    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head]
  end
end
```

and in the React package.json I have:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:3000",
```

My rails routes are:

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern         Controller#Action
  dogs GET    /dogs(.:format)     dogs#index
       POST   /dogs(.:format)     dogs#create
   dog GET    /dogs/:id(.:format) dogs#show
       PATCH  /dogs/:id(.:format) dogs#update
       PUT    /dogs/:id(.:format) dogs#update
       DELETE /dogs/:id(.:format) dogs#destroy
```

Current, I can successfully get and display a list of Dogs in React using:

```
window.fetch('dogs')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => this.setState({dogs: json}))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

However, I want to be able to edit each dog. So I have the following in a 'Dog' React component to handle updates:

```
handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    let url = `dogs/${this.state.id}`
    let data = {
      dog: {
        id: this.state.id,
        name: this.state.name,
        age: this.state.age,
        sex: this.state.sex,
        description: this.state.description
      }
    }

    let updateDog = {
      method: 'PUT',
      body: data
    }
    fetch(url, updateDog)
      .then(json => console.log(json))
      .catch(error => console.log(error))
  }
```

(I'll use the response to set state eventually, however just logging it for now)
In Chrome's console, when I submit the form I get the following error:

```
PUT http://localhost:3000/dogs/1 400 (Bad Request)
Dog.jsx:61 Response {type: "cors", url: "http://localhost:3000/dogs/1", redirected: false, status: 400, ok: false…}
```

But when I use Postman to submit the following PUT to http://localhost:3000/dogs/1, it successfully updates the dog! What am I doing wrong?

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Lord Barkington",
  "age": 7,
  "sex": "M",
  "description": "Pieces of Eight jolly boat mutiny me cable spike Sail ho ho draught reef sails grapple schooner topsail Yellow Jack.",
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, does it work if you set `origins '*'` in your confit middleware settings? Or possibly adding `127.0.0.1:3000`. Also be sure to run `spring stop` after you've stopped your server to reload the changes.

Comment: Unfortunately I still get a bad request.

Comment: I can tell you off-the-bat that your the `proxy` setting in your `package.json` needs to be the URL of your API. That means it should be port 3001 in your case (where Rails is listening) but you currently have port 3000 (where NPM is serving React)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a different set up (PHP API and React in frontend). The reason for the error is that POST requests operate differently in this situation:

1. Send a preflight request of type OPTIONS
2. If it was successful send the actual POST request with the data

You can see practical examples on this in [this blog post](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/). Try to open your Chrome Console (network tab). There you will find both, the OPTIONS request and the POST request together with their content and responses.

Postman has a special behavior, not sending preflight requests (read it [here](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/170)) which is why your browser test do not work even if postman does.

**Solution**

Make sure that your rails router accepts OPTIONS requests and returns a 200 OK.